# Recurrence relation - what sum is it?

Tags: big-o, recurrence

I need to solve: T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)

when I find the general T(n) = T(n-k) + k O(1)
what sum is it? I mean when I reach the base case: n-k=1; k=n-1
Is it "sum k, k=1 to n"? but the result of this sum is n(n-1)/2 and I know that the result is O(n).
So I know that I don't need a sum with this relation but what sum is correct for this recurrence relation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we make the (reasonable) assumption that T(0) = 0 (or T(1) = O(1)), then we can apply your
T(n) = T(n - k) + k⋅O(1) to k = n and obtain

T(n) = T(n - n) + n⋅O(1) = 0 + n⋅O(1) = O(n).

Edit: if you insist on representing the recurrence as a sum, here it is:

T(n) = T(n - 1) + O(1) = T(n - 2) + O(1) + O(1) = ... = Σ<sub>k = 1,...n</sub> O(1) = n⋅O(1) = O(n)

Comment: ok thanks, but in terms of summation? I know the result and the way to solve it but I'd like to understand what sum is related to this relation, I mean how can I write "k times O(1)" in terms of sum? Something like sum of k, from k=1 to n?
thanks

Comment: Added representation as a sum. Is this what you were looking for?